# New version of RazorEngine throws TemplateParsingException saying "no matching start tag"

Tags: c#, razorengine

I upgraded RazorEngine (https://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorEngine) from 2.1 to 3.4.1 and my templates are now not compiling. I am getting exception TemplateParsingException saying that:

Encountered end tag "body" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

But of course my body tag is closed. It compiled just fine in old version. Did the syntax of razor "langugage" changed?

Here is the template:

```
 @{ var Title = Model.Page.Title ;
                   var Description = Model.Page.Description;
                   var Articles = Model.Site.Articles;
                   var SiteUrl = Model.Site.WebsiteUrl;
             }<!doctype html>
<html lang="cs-cz">
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>


            @{
                foreach(var Article in Articles){
                if(Article.HasNextArticle && Article.Date != null && Article.NextArticle.Date != null && Article.Date.Year != Article.NextArticle.Date.Year){
                    @:<div class="year">@Article.Date.Year</div><br/>               
                }
                @:<span class="articletitle"><a href="@Article.Url">@Article.Title</a></span><br/>
                @:<div class="articledesc">@Article.Description</div>

            } }

    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: By trial and error I figured, that it compiles when I remove the "@:" symbol.

Comment: Then either delete your question or if you think that it could help others, post an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I also have this issue, for old engine we needed some unmatched (), {}, the new engine enforces correct C# style.